# A universe with no coronaviruses

Tags: viruses

Starting a new TTRPG campaign, I mentioned the players that it takes place in our contemporary universe, but with no COVID-19 epidemics. In fact, I went so far as to say that that version of our universe is perfectly equal to ours, but no coronaviruses exist.

What have I done? Would that imply some unforeseen consequences, apart from the non-existence of this and other diseases? Say, obscure but wide-ranging differences in some remote phase of evolution on Earth?

Comment: Looks to me that you just pruned a minute twig from the tree of evolution. There's plenty to grow into it's place once it's gone. This is the sort of "what if?" [open ended question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) that can't be answered here. If you can narrow it down to a single issue that you're trying to resolve, then ...

Comment: It might be sufficient if you'd make up a universe where there is no hysteria generated over a flu. Should solve all your problems in regards to evolution and biology.

Comment: Why specifically coronaviruses? The vast majority of them produce nothing more than common colds. *This* particular COVID-19 is novel, and therefore a little more virulent than its cousins.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. This sounds like a different flavor of "what are the consequences of X?", X being removal of coronavirus. That type of question is always too broad and thus not a good fit here. You can find more info in the [help]

Comment: @AlexP: It was a spur-of-the-moment decision, little more than a joke, but later I asked myself if it might have wider consequences.

Comment: Sorry, everybody, I didn't realise that my question's format is not suitable here. Feel free to delete it, if it's off-topic. I was hoping in some objective factor I don't know about. For instance, if Neanderthals never existed, we Sapiens would lack the part of our own DNA we have derived from them, and one could possibly deduce the physical (or other?) differences in us.